# Need help with a sub query/group/order (get latest comment for each ordered topic)

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Hey guys I have a query that currently finds the latest comment for each of a user's topics and then orders topics by that comment's timestamp. **What I want to do is expand on this query's use and print the latest comment for each topic.** The problem with this query is that while it orders the topics correctly, it prints seemingly random comments for each topic. I am trying to implement a sub query but I am not quite sure how to approach it. I was thinking that I just had to somehow use this query to get the comments. If anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate it.

**Here is what I think I need to add**

```
SELECT * FROM comments where topic_id='$topic_id' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

**Here is the query I need to modify**

```
SELECT topic.topic_title, topic.content_type, topic.subject_id, topic.creator, topic.description, topic.topic_id,comments.message,comments.user
      FROM comments
      JOIN topic ON topic.topic_id = comments.topic_id
      WHERE topic.creator = '$user' AND comments.timestamp > $week
      GROUP BY topic_id ORDER BY MAX(comments.timestamp) DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of the greatest-n-per-group problem, which comes up on Stack Overflow frequently.  Follow the tag for more examples.

```
SELECT t.topic_title, t.content_type, t.subject_id, t.creator, t.description, 
  t.topic_id, c1.message, c1.user
FROM topic t
JOIN comments c1 ON (t.topic_id = c1.topic_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments c2
  ON (t.topic_id = c2.topic_id AND c1.timestamp < c2.timestamp)
WHERE t.creator = ? AND c1.timestamp > ?
  AND c2.topic_id IS NULL
ORDER BY c1.timestamp DESC;
```

PS: Use query parameters (`?`) for dynamic values, to reduce the risk of SQL injection.

Comment: works like a charm Bill, thanks. You even did it without a subquery which I understand can have performance issues! As for the (?) suggestion, I understand these are used in prepared statements. I am planning to replace all my mysql statements with mysqli prepared statements, do you have any good suggestions for references?

Comment: I prefer using PDO, the usage for parameters is much simpler than mysqli.  It's not that hard, there are good examples in the docs e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: PS I am really glad you put me on to PDO instead of mysqli, it is much simpler and has a lot of attractive features.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your $week var is doing, but I hope it is date formatted.

How about this?  I suspect it will be slow, but it is the first thing that came to mind:

```
SELECT t.topic_title, t.content_type, t.subject_id, t.creator,
   t.description, t.topic_id, c.message, c.user
FROM topic t
INNER JOIN comments c
  ON t.topic_id = c.topic_id
  AND c.comment_id = (select max(c2.comment_id) 
                    from comments c2
                    where c2.topic_id = topic.topic_id)
WHERE t.creator = '$user' 
  AND c.timestamp > $week
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.topic_title, t.content_type, t.subject_id, t.creator, t.description, t.topic_id, c.message, c.user
from comments c
inner join (
    SELECT cc.topic_id, max(cc.timestamp) as MaxTimestamp
    FROM comments cc
    inner JOIN topic t ON t.topic_id = cc.topic_id
    WHERE t.creator = '$user' AND cc.timestamp > $week      
    group by cc.topic_id
) cm on c.topic_id = cm.topic_id and c.timestamp = cm.MaxTimestamp
inner JOIN topic t ON t.topic_id = c.topic_id
```